# Why does "Alt Gr + {" open the Task Runner in VS 2015 RC

Tags: visual-studio

Everything was working perfect. Today suddenly VS 2015 RC started to open the Task Runner instead of what it should do "{".

Any suggestions?

When I open Notepad it works.

I guess the issue is somehow related to the fact that the shortcut is similar to Ctrl Gr + ä.

I never changed anything. Strange. How to fix this?

[image: Ctrl Gr]

Comment: What is your KeyBoard-Language/Layout?

Comment: Swiss German is my layout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why that happened, but you can try the following to fix it:

1. Open *Tools - Options*, select *Environment - Keyboard*.
2. Under "Show commands containing", type `taskrunner`.
3. The *View.TaskRunnerExplorer* entry will appear in the list. Select it.
4. Select the offending shortcut in the "Shortcuts for selected command" list, and click "Remove". **Or**, you can also focus the textbox under "Press shortcut keys", press a new key combination, and click "Assign" (although I'm not sure if this will remove the old one).

Comment: Perfect! never made this shortcut. But it is removed now. I cannot understand what happened. Maybe somehow related to that I am connecting to the machine via RDP. Sometimes strange things then occur regarding keyboard combinations.

Comment: I have experienced similar problems in the past when using Visual Studio while a RDP session is open (in my case I use a Spanish keyboard). But it was about five years ago, and it seems that it's not fixed yet...

Comment: It's the default shortcut in Visual Studio 2015 RC since a few weeks. Me and a couple of mates made the same experience :-)

Comment: What? Crazy people :)

Comment: Assigning, even when it shows *nothing* currently assigned, does overwrite the old one. Making it work. Thank you. -- Make sure you select *Text Editor*.